# Where are Lock Screen pictures stored in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

According to some websites, the lock screen pictures are stored at: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\LockScreen_A

But I cannot find the LockScreen_A folder.

I guess this is not valid in Windows 8.1 anymore.

I am not interested in the c:\Windows\Web\Screen pictures (default pictures that come with the operating system).

I want to keep a copy of the current lock screen picture before setting a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Aren't all the lock screen pictures(default or not default) stored at **C:\Windows\Web\Screen** anyway?

Anyway if it isn't, did you change your lock screen to display your own pictures?

Refer [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows-8/desktop-background-lock-screen), it shows that you chose the folder which contains the lock screen pictures.

**EDIT:**
If your Lock Screen picture was synced, then it should be in your **Skydrive/Onedrive** folder as it was synced along with the personalisation settings from your previous computer. Have you checked there yet?

Comment: My lock screen picture is not in c:\windows\web\screen, and I set it before using a different computer, and was synchronized into this one.

Comment: it is not in my OneDrive folder, at least not in the files I can modify or delete. Where are the personalization settings stored?

Comment: Is your Backup Settings in Sync Settings set to On?